# Error in Jmeter Master Machine "java.net.NoRouteToHostException"

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I am setting up distributed testing in Linux machines with a master and a slave. Need your advice to overcome the below error message

```
"Exception Creating a connection to 192.xx.xx. xx ;nested exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: no route to host ( Host Unreachable )"
```

I did the following steps

1. Ensured Master and Slave has the same version of Jmeter
2. Added the slave machine IP in Master's Jmeter.properites
3. Created a keystore file in master and copied the generated
   rmi_keystore.jks to slave machine bin folder
4. Run jmeter-server file in the slave machine ( There was an error
   hence added the slave machines ip in
   RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.xx.xx.xx)- success up
   and running
5. Run the intended jmx file in master Run - Remote start - Slave
   machine
6. Error Exception Creating a connection to 192.xx.xx.xx ; nested
   exception is java.net.NoRouteToHostException: no route to host (Host
   Unreachable )

I did check the connectivity between two machines when I ping i was able to reach each machine from one another,

Could be an issue with Firewall or port ? not sure

I have been banging my head , any pointers would be helpfull

thanks in advance

Comment: An OS networking error, can you ping those hosts on command line?

Comment: yes am able to ping master from slave & vice versa

Comment: Try to log the host IP from java code to make sure is correctly read from -D option.

Comment: Sorry, i coudnt get you,  can you explain a bit more detail please

Comment: You are passing the host IP from command line as `RMI_HOST_DEF=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.xx.xx.xx`, Try to log that value to check what it's really getting.

Answer (score 1):

1. check your Slave from Master

   > example: nc -zvw3 192.168.1.31 1099
2. if you get Ncat: No route to host then disable firewall on Salve and Master:

   - systemctl stop firewalld
   - systemctl disable firewalld